# Shared prefrence overwrites

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-recyclerview

I save a string set in shared preferences that loads to my watchlist. When the user clicks on a button, in the movie's page, it takes the movie's name, title and release date and store them in a JSON object. All of them are stored as String. The problem persists when I try to add a movie in the watchlist, each new movie I add, the last movie gets overwritten, which means I can only have one movie in my watchlist at all time.

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("WatchlistData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                obj.put("name", name);
                obj.put("date", releaseDate);
                obj.put("platform", platform);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
            set.add(obj.toString());

            editor.putStringSet("setOfStrings", set);



            editor.commit(); //saved

        }
    });
```

Watchlist fragment OnCreateView

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_watchlist, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.watchlist);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mWatchlistAdapter = new WatchlistAdapter(getActivity(), loadFromStorage());
    mWatchlistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mWatchlistAdapter);
    return view;
}
```

The loadFromStorage, loads my xml file in the recyclerview, this method is passed in my adapter constructor.

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("WatchlistData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    ArrayList<watchlist> items = new ArrayList<watchlist>();

    Set<String> set = mPrefs.getStringSet("setOfStrings", null); //retrieving set of strings

    if (set == null){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        //for every string in set
        for (String s : set) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s); //for every JSONObject String
                String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                String date = jsonObject.getString("date");
                String platform = jsonObject.getString("platform");

                watchlist newGame = new watchlist();

                newGame.setGame(name);
                newGame.setDate(date);
                newGame.setPlatform(platform);
                items.add(newGame);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `SharedPreferences` replaces the old data with the newer one. What you can do is, get the old data first then append with with the newer one,

```
//Extract the value stored in SharedPreferences
String value = prefs.getString(<Key>, <DefaultValue>);

//Append to the extracted value
String appendedValue = append(value, newValue);

//Write the result back to SharedPreferences
editor.putString(<Key>, appendedValue).commit();
```

`SharedPreferenced` are made for lite weight data but not for heavy storage. So, according to your requirement you should write the data to a JSON/XML file in the external storage and read it back later.

Comment: Could you give me a tutorial on saving as JSON/XML in the external storage?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are just overwriting the stringset in SharedPreferences every time you put something there, which is why you only ever see the last result:

```
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        set.add(obj.toString());

        editor.putStringSet("setOfStrings", set);
```

You are just created a new 'set' on each click and saving that to "setOfStrings".

I was considering a similar implementation myself for a project, but saw that it became an issue manipulating the StringSet from SharedPreferences. For reference,  [documentation on Android developers site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet(java.lang.String, java.util.Set))
states, 
*"Note that you must not modify the set instance returned by this call. The consistency of the stored data is not guaranteed if you do, nor is your ability to modify the instance at all."*

There are workarounds to this, but from what I understand it is better to avoid using SharedPreferences for data such as this which will be manipulated often, as it is just saved as an xml file prone to issues- you may want to consider implementing that information in a SQLite database.

Comment: Could you give me a tutorial on saving as JSON/XML in the external storage?